# How can I configure the heap size when starting a Spring Boot application with embedded Tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, heap-memory

I am trying to deploy a [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) powered web app to production. The app is built with Spring Boot 1.0.1 and has the default Tomcat 7 embedded as application server. I want to allocate larger memory to the app when start the app with `java -jar myapp.jar` command line.

Should I use [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) parameter such as `-Xms -Xmx` or use environment variable such as `JAVA_OPTS`? I have tried to look for the answer in documentation or google it, but I did not get an answer. Can anyone give some hints?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use whatever normal mechanism you would to set up the JVM. Documentation is available on the command line:

```
$ java -X
...
-Xms<size>        Set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        Set maximum Java heap size
...
```

Comment: So, can I increase it way more than normal(like 10X)? What will be the overhead for application or JVM or machine?

Answer (score 75):

If starting the application with the [`spring-boot` plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html):

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xmx512m" -Drun.profiles=dev
```

Otherwise if [running `java -jar`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html#using-boot-running-as-a-packaged-application):

```
java -Xmx512m -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar app.jar
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6. The [Spring Boot Maven plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html) specifies that it should work, but it doesn't.  I see two options, either specify the configuration into the pom.xml (that works), or specify the version of the Spring Boot Maven plugin to be 1.5.9-RELEASE (that works too).

Comment: Like Vlad Dinulescu mentioned it works only with a set of Spring Boot versions. For one version it worked, for 2.0.3.RELEASE it doesn't. Solution in answer by Zhang Buzz works.

Answer (score 45):

Since this is specifically a *Spring Boot* question, I'd argue that a more useful answer than @DaveSyer's is this:

You can drop a `.conf` file in the same directory as your [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28Sun_file_format%29) file that is effectively a shell script.

For example,

```
$ ls
myapp.conf
myapp.war
$ cat myapp.conf
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -Xms256m"
```

Any configuration you do there will be run before the Spring Boot embedded Tomcat starts up. Personally, I version control a `.conf.example` file in my application itself and then drop a copy of it on each server I deploy to.

Of course, anything you set in that `.conf` file is overridable with command-line operations.

Comment: This is so beautiful.  And it works for .jar files as well.  I <3 Spring Boot

Comment: Since which version is available?

Comment: I tried with spring boot 1.5.9, but it didn't pickup my conf: export JAVA_OPTS="java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" in .conf file named the same as jar file. Executed with java -jar using nohup.

Answer (score 19):

For Spring Boot 2, you have to specify the heap size in the `pom.xml` file as below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>-Xmx64m</jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 14):

For Spring Boot 1, the Maven argument to specify in the plugin configuration is `jvmArguments`, and the user property is [`run.jvmArguments`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html):

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m"
```

For Spring Boot 2, the Maven argument to specify in the plugin configuration is also `jvmArguments`, but the user property is now [`spring-boot.run.jvmArguments`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html):

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m"
```

So if you use the plugin configuration way, both for Spring Boot 1 and 2 you can do that:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>
            -Xms4048m
            -Xmx8096m
        </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Property spring-boot.run.jvmArguments works. Thanks.