# Spring boot application as a service + VM Options

Tags: linux, spring-boot, systemd, jvm-arguments

I have a Spring boot application that is started as a service using Linux's systemd.

It is based on this documentation :
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

With the default script, the jar file start. It works fine.

/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=myapp
ExecStart=/var/myapp/myapp.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I want to add VM Option when the jar start.
I tried to add a .conf file to the project but it doesn't work.

/var/myapp/myapp.conf :

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256M -Xmx512M
```

How can I add JVM option to start the application with systemd ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution here :
[how to configure heap size when start a spring-boot application with embedded tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072187/how-to-configure-heap-size-when-start-a-spring-boot-application-with-embedded-to?rq=1)

The content of my .conf file was wrong.
I need too write this :

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

Now when I run "service myapp start", it start with the good heap size.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-when-it-runs) you can simply add an environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` if that's enough for you.

The way we start the apps with custom ENV variables and systemd would look like this for your project:

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=myapp
ExecStart=source /var/myapp/myapp.conf; java -jar /var/myapp/myapp.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Basically sourcing the ENV config directly will expose the ENV variables to the application

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another good way is to create a configuration file `myapp.conf` in the same directory with the `myapp.jar` file

```
/var/myapp/
```

and put the following content:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

Then restart the application.

Note that the name of configuration file should be the same with the jar file except the extension, `.conf` instead of `.jar` or `.war`.

This way have some other advantages:

- Keep the settings separately for the `myapp` application only.
- We can have additional parameters in the file too.

More detail can be found [here](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2020/05/29/install-a-spring-boot-application-as-a-linux-service/).