# Spring Data JPA findAllById with 10K id's

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 10k IDs and need to fetch all records from the DB, but `findAllById` throws `stack overflow` and couldn't complete the transaction.

How can I solve this?

```
//itemsList has 10k records in csv format
List<Item> items = factory.getIemRepository().findAllById(itemsList);
```

Comment: Don't try to get them all in one query, but process them in batches instead of for example 100 objects each.

Comment: As a quick guess, do you use `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE id IN (...)` as the query.  The `IN` command has a limitation on many implementations which means it can't exceed (I think) 4k elements.  You can make the query into `WHERE id = ... OR id = ... OR ...`, or batch them up like the person above suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The findAllById will generate an SQL statement with an IN clause (i.e. where ID in (val1, val2, ... val10000).

This causes an error in Oracle (max 1000) and possibly other DBs. If not, it probably uses all the memory available to store the list of IDs.

There are several options, but I would recommend storing the 10k IDs in a temporary table and perform a SQL join with your main table. This will perform much better than any batching or breaking the query in several sub-queries.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your database, most DBs limit the number of IDs you can query at once. Assuming that 10k is not over this limit for your particular database, the `stackoverflow` you are mentioning is most likely because you are returning 10k results and your system has run out of memory.

Try increasing the heap space for Java. For example,

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xmx1024m" -Drun.profiles=dev
```

Ref: *[How can I configure the heap size when starting a Spring Boot application with embedded Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072187/how-to-configure-heap-size-when-starting-a-spring-boot-application-with-embedded)*

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method with query `WHERE id IN (:ids)` in your repository and call it like this:

```
private List getEdcsByEdcCodes(Collection<Long> idslist) {
    final int chunkSize = 500;
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    Collection<Collection<Long>> devidedIdsList = edcCodes.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(resultList -> counter.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize))
        .values();

    return devidedIdsList.stream()
        .map(idsList -> findbyIdList(idsList))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saying finaAllXXXX() is not a good way. We should either perform a more specific condition base query or use pagination. The increasing size of memory is not a solution because of data will increase gradually.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting